# Migration from Oracle Database 11g to AWS RDS Oracle 19c Failures

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, datapump

When Migrating from Oracle Database 11g to AWS RDS Oracle Database 19c using the Oracle Datapump tool for export and the RDS Datapump API for Import resulted in some nasty errors.

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39143: dump file "/rdsdbdata/datapump/test.dmp" may be an original export dump file
```

What I have tried

- Changing the ownership of the dmp file
- Using the full schema option
- Adding the credentials
- Migrating from oracle database 11g to Oracle Database 12c using traditional datapump functionality to resolve the compatibility issues resulted in the same issue mentioned above.

Comment: How was test.dmp created? As per error its created using exp utility rather then expdp.

Comment: Correct the exp utility was used to create it, however when using the impdp whether its from oracle or AWS RDS Oracle Import API it throws this issue. See link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.DataPump.html to AWS RDS Oracle Import API.

Comment: You cannot use impdp on files generated using exp. Either recrete dump using expdp or use imp rather then impdp.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the exp generated file to data pump generated files? I won't mind using another server for this right now.

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by doing the following:

1. Granting permission to the schema to access the directory I was interested in storing the exported DMP file on the server.
2. Exporting the DMP using expdp (Data Pump)